# How to chain mutiples IN AND on WHERE in SQL?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I want to do something like :

```
SELECT  "recipes"."id"
FROM "recipes"
    INNER JOIN "groups" ON "groups"."recipe_id" = "recipes"."id"
    INNER JOIN "steps" ON "steps"."group_id" = "groups"."id"
    INNER JOIN "steps_ingredients_memberships" ON "steps_ingredients_memberships"."step_id" = "steps"."id"
    INNER JOIN "ingredients" ON "ingredients"."id" =  "steps_ingredients_memberships"."ingredient_id"
 WHERE (ingredients.id IN (5, 6) AND ingredients.id IN (10, 11))
 LIMIT 10
```

But this request return 0 rows...
I know this request can't work but i can't find a solution

I want to get "Recipes" that have ingredients 5 `OR` 6 `AND` 10 `OR` 11.
Think like :

```
5 = tomatoes
6 = big tomatoes
10 = potatoes
11 = big potatoes
```

I want "Recipes" with tomatoes `OR` big tomatoes `AND` potatoes `OR` big potatoes.

**Solution adopted**

Because ingredients can be random, I wrote a scope :

```
  scope :ingredients_filtering, lambda { |ingredients|
    return if ingredients.nil?

    queries = []
    ingredients.each do |ingredient|
      related_ids = ingredient.related_ids.uniq.join(', ')
      queries << "BOOL_OR(ingredients.id IN (#{related_ids}))"
    end
    group(:id).having(queries.join(' AND '))
  }
```

Thanks you to all of you ! :)

Comment: Is ruby-on-rails tag relevant or you need a plain sql solution?

Comment: Either GROUP BY, or self join.

Comment: I put the ruby-on-rails tag because if there is a solution in ruby-on-rails it's better but I don't think so ...

Comment: @mjerem34 be careful with that as String concatenation could be potentially dangerous depending on where the data comes from. I have adapted my answer to implement your desired functionality leveraging `arel`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To expand on [@MrYoshiji's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/976775/mryoshiji) comment [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54750813/how-to-chain-mutiples-in-and-on-where-in-sql/54750931#comment96285543_54750931) we can make this more "railsy" as follows:

```
ingredients_table = Ingredient.arel_table
ingredient_list1 = [5,6]
ingredient_list2 = [10,11]
condition = Arel::Nodes::NamedFunction.new(
              'BOOL_OR',[ingredients_table[:id].in(ingredient_list1)]
            ).and(
              Arel::Nodes::NamedFunction.new(
                'BOOL_OR',[ingredients_table[:id].in(ingredient_list2)]
              )
            )
recipes = Recipe.joins(groups: { 
                       steps: { 
                         steps_ingredients_memberships: :ingredients
                       }
                     })
        .group('recipes.id')
        .having(condition)
```

This will produce SQL similar to the linked answer: (Provided by [@ThorstenKettner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2270762/thorsten-kettner)) e.g.

```
SELECT recipes.*
FROM recipes 
  JOIN groups ON groups.recipe_id = recipes.id 
  JOIN steps ON steps.group_id = groups.id 
  JOIN steps_ingredients_memberships ON steps_ingredients_memberships.step_id = steps.id 
  JOIN ingredients ON ingredients.id = steps_ingredients_memberships.ingredient_id 
GROUP BY 
   recipes.id
HAVING 
  BOOL_OR(ingredients.id IN (5, 6)) AND 
  BOOL_OR(ingredients.id IN (10, 11))
```

However it offers the flexibility to change `ingredient_list1` and `ingredient_list2` in a far more efficient manner without concern for escaping and the like.

BTW to address your comment:

> *"I put the ruby-on-rails tag because if there is a solution in ruby-on-rails it's better but I don't think so ..."*

`arel` can assemble any query you can imagine (it can assemble invalid/fragmented SQL too). If it is valid SQL `ActiveRecord` can run it so if you are using rails and have query questions definitely include the [ruby-on-rails](/questions/tagged/ruby-on-rails) tag like you did.

**Update** (based on your posted solution) but using `arel` rather than string concatenation

```
scope :ingredients_filtering, lambda { |ingredients|
  return unless ingredients
  ingredients_table = Ingredient.arel_table
  conditions = ingredients.map do |ingredient|
    Arel::Nodes::NamedFunction.new(
          'BOOL_OR',[ingredients_table[:id].in(ingredient.related_ids)]
        )
  end.reduce(&:and)
  group(:id).having(conditions)
}
```

Comment: since this is Postgres, would it make sense to aggregate the ingredients list to an array, and then use array functions check presence of ingredients?

Comment: @GarrettMotzner to be honest I am not all that familiar with Postgres and its functions. I am very familiar with how `arel` handles query assembly and its cross capacity with native rails queries. If you can post the syntax for the aggregation I can certainly convert it to `arel`

Answer (score 2):

You want aggregation. Group by recipe and see if it has the desired ingredients.

```
SELECT r.id 
FROM recipes r 
JOIN groups g ON g.recipe_id = r.id 
JOIN steps s ON s.group_id = g.id 
JOIN steps_ingredients_memberships sim ON sim.step_id = s.id 
JOIN ingredients i ON i.id = sim.ingredient_id 
GROUP BY r.id
HAVING BOOL_OR(i.id IN (5, 6)) AND BOOL_OR(i.id IN (10, 11));
```

Comment: You can translate the above with ActiveRecord into: `Recipe.joins(groups: { steps: { steps_ingredients_memberships: :ingredients).group('recipes.id').having('BOOL_OR(i.id IN (5, 6)) AND BOOL_OR(i.id IN (10, 11))')`

Comment: Thanks @MrYoshiji, I used your solution ! I'll update my post to write solution I used

Answer (score 0):

use `GROUP BY` and `HAVING`:

```
SELECT  "recipes"."id"
FROM "recipes"
    INNER JOIN "groups" ON "groups"."recipe_id" = "recipes"."id"
    INNER JOIN "steps" ON "steps"."group_id" = "groups"."id"
    INNER JOIN "steps_ingredients_memberships" ON "steps_ingredients_memberships"."step_id" = "steps"."id"
    INNER JOIN "ingredients" ON "ingredients"."id" =  "steps_ingredients_memberships"."ingredient_id"
 GROUP BY "recipes"."id"
 HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN ingredients.id IN (5, 6) THEN 1 END) > 0 
    AND COUNT(CASE WHEN ingredients.id IN (10, 11) THEN 1 END) > 0
```